# How to format a sql column with comma to number format

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have a data table where I have numbers expressed in the following format:

```
Incorrect  | What I want to format it to
------------------------------------------
123,452,03 | 123,452.03
234.00     | 234.00
456,02     | 456.02
```

The challenge that I have is some numbers have more than one comma. I know this can be solved via regex, but can use some help in constructing the string. The logic should be as following:

1. Check if string has comma
2. If after the comma there are two numbers and they are at the end of the string
3. Replace the comma value with a period
4. If after the comma there are three numeric values, or if is in the middle of the string, do nothing.

EDIT: Using Sql Server to construct the expression.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The regex functionality can be quite different, depending on product used.)

Comment: Using sql server :)

Comment: It's a bad idea to store numeric data as strings. Use proper column data type, and you will not have this problem.

Comment: Normalize your schema. See ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) (Spoiler: Yes, it is.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a bad idea to store numbers in string columns. And then even store invalid numbers. Well, check the antepenultimate character. If it's a comma change it to a dot.

```
case when left(right(str, 3), 1) = ',' then
  stuff(str, len(str) - 2, 1, '.')
else
  str
end
```

Or if all numbers end with two decimals just:

```
stuff(str, len(str) - 2, 1, '.')
```

(Once you've repaired your numbers, you should put them in a numeric column and drop the existing text column.)

Comment: This works, thank you! Sadly, not my data, it is a data feed we get from a very antiquated system. I will just modify the query to convert it into a numeric column.